# SAML metadata file and SSO

Tags: java, saml

**Aim**

To navigate to a url using SSO.

**Info**

I have been given a SP SAML metadata file by a third party.

**Question**

Using Java & JavaScript, how do I navigate to the endpoint url?

I have seen a number of articles on SAML architecture , but cannot seem to find how to just navigate to an endpoint. I presume this could even be tested in Postman just like a JWT can.

**More info**

I am new to SAML, but have been reading up on the topic. From what I can tell, is I am the 'Principal' and the third-party is the 'Service Provider'. It looks like they used [onelogin](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) to generate the SP metatdata file.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2020-10-14T14:43:29Z" cacheDuration="PT604800S" entityID="https://testentityid">
  <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>certificate</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>certificate</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://logoutendpoint"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://consumeendpoint" index="1"/>
  </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Principal is the user the IdP is authenticating. A simple flow is essentially, using the [SAML Web Browser SSO Profile](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.Web%20Browser%20SSO%20Profile%7Coutline):

1. User goes to a resource at a Service Provider (SP)
2. The SP detects the user has no session and redirects the browser to the SSO endpoint of the IdP
3. The IdP authenticates the user (Principal)
4. The IdP redirects the browser to the SP's `AssertionConsumerService` URL along with a SAML Response encoded in the URL, which contains the Principal's SAML Attributes.

There are various SAML Request/Response examples [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php) and various ways of the SP redirecting the browser, either via `GET` or `POST` SAML binding. Plus a lot of other essentials such as certificates and signatures based on keys in the metadata of each entity (IdP and SP).

Normally you have to sign a SAML Request using your private key and the other entity (IdP for example) verifies that signature using your public key from your SAML metadata, `<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">/X509Data/X509Certificate` above. An unsolicited SAML Response sent to an SP may not be relevant but it would need to be signed with the private key of the IdP and the SP would need to have the public key of the IdP to verify the signature.

Comment: Hi @codebrane, thank you for your explanation above. That does make the workings of SAML more clear. Question: do you know where I can find examples/tutorials on, as the 'Principal' using a website, how to redirect to the SP? I can see from your link above, that there are examples of request/response objects, but I don't know how to actually implement it. Do I call an endpoint? I cannot seem to find examples of this either.

Comment: The profile is browser based so you don't call anything. You just redirect the browser to the SP's AssertionConsumerService with the param ?SAMLResponse=... but you'll need to construct a SAML Response, sign it, perhaps encrypt it and base64 encode it. Implementing your own IdP isn't recommended for these reasons